# What are open subsets of half-open interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

What are open subsets of half-open interval of $\mathbb{R}$? We are talking about standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

The half-open interval itself is not open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition (of the so-called subspace topology), open sets in $[a,b)$ are of the form $O \cap [a,b)$ for $O$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ in the standard topology.

In particular, $[a,b) = \mathbb{R} \cap [a,b)$ is open in $[a,b)$ (not in the reals, but that doesn't matter).

If you think about it, $O \subseteq [a,b)$ is open iff for all $x \in O$ we have that if $x \neq a$, there exists some open interval around $x$ that is a subset of $O$, and if $x = a$, there exists some $y \in [a,b)$ such that $[a,y) \subseteq O$. I.e. all points of $[a,b)$ have the usual neighbourhoods except $a$ which only has "right facing" ones, because the points to left are not part of $[a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Extra question, are subset of half-open interval that itself is half-open a clopen?

Comment: @Zzz no, $[a,b)$ is connected and has no clopen subsets, except $[a,b)$ and $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose (a,b] is a half-open interval, then the open set in it is a union of $(a,b]\cap (c,d)'s $,where c and d in R.

Comment: Also,notice c<d! This means (a,b] inherits the standard topology in R.